# Rerunning test in jsp page without reloading page

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Is it possible to rerun a `<c:choose>` block of code as shown bellow without reloading the JSP page?

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${salary <= 0}">
       Salary is very low to survive.
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${salary > 1000}">
        Salary is very good.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        No comment sir...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

This would need to be done in the case that the value of salary changed and a different resut needs to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rerun the `c:choose` block without reloading the JSP. The JSP is processed on the server side and then sent to the client. The client only gets the rendered result of the `c:choose`, not the JSP itself.

When you use JavaScript to update the value, then either repeat the logic in the JavaScript based on the value of `salary` or request the label via an XMLHttpRequest.